# shopping cart with duplicated items

Tags: javascript, html

I have an array called cart and need to add the product the customer has selected to the final shopping cart. So basically when I click on one product first (does not matter how many times), you can see the item added  correctly to the cart. If I close the modal because I need to add another product, the first item shows duplicated.

this is the HTML that I have

```html
<div
    class="modal fade"
    id="cartModal"
    tabindex="-1"
    aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel"
    aria-hidden="true"
>
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">
                    <i class="fas fa-cart-arrow-down"></i> My Cart
                </h5>
                <button
                    type="button"
                    class="btn-close"
                    data-bs-dismiss="modal"
                    aria-label="Close"
                ></button>
            </div>
            <!-- shopping cart modal -->
            <div class="modal-body">
                <h3 class="text-center bill px-5">Shopping Cart</h3>
                <table class="table" id="shopping-table">
                    
                    <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <th scope="col">Product</th>
                            <th scope="col">Price</th>
                            <th scope="col">Qty.</th>
                            <th scope="col">
                                Total <small>(with discount)</small>
                            </th>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody id="cart_list">
                        
                    </tbody>
                </table>
                <div class="text-center fs-3">
                    <span id="total_price"></span>
                </div>
                <div class="text-center">
                    <a href="checkout.html" class="btn btn-primary m-3"
                        >Checkout</a
                    >
                    <a
                        href="javascript:void(0)"
                        onclick="cleanCart()"
                        class="btn btn-primary m-3"
                        >Clean Cart</a
                    >
                </div>
            </div>
            <!-- fin de shopping cart modal  -->
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

this is the javascript logic that I have applied. Please be aware that the cart has been passed as a parameter from another function.

```js
function printCart(cart) {
    let shoppingCart = document.getElementById("shopping-table");
    let tableBody = document.getElementById("cart_list");

    console.log(cart)

    cart.forEach((p) => {
        let row = document.createElement("tr");

        let td = document.createElement("td");
        td.style.fontWeight = "bold";
        td.innerText = p.name;
        row.appendChild(td);

        td = document.createElement("td");
        td.innerText = p.price;
        row.appendChild(td);

        td = document.createElement("td");
        td.innerText = p.quantity;
        row.appendChild(td);

        td = document.createElement("td");
        td.innerText = p.subtotalWithDiscount;
        row.appendChild(td);

        tableBody.appendChild(row);
    });

    shoppingCart.appendChild(tableBody);
}
```

[image]

Please let me know how to fix this. if you prefer you can check the whothin here https://github.com/valerioprds/sprint-3.git

Comment: Can you create a reproducible example?

Answer (score 0):

Here is the think. What comes to my mind is, when you open the modal, you will run `printCart` function. When you take a look on it, it always re-append `shopping-table` child, whenever you run the function. So it is like you are re-printing all of data, without deleting the previous one (because you are using appendChild method)

There is some solution, first you can reset the table body first before re-print the data by making `reset()` function to clear the table body.

The other solution is not using appendChild, but using innerHTML property. It could be something like this

```
let tableBody = document.getElementById("cart_list");

let rows = '';
cart.forEach(p => {
 rows += `<tr><td>${p.name}</td><td>${.price}</td></tr>`
})

tableBody.innerHTML = rows;
```

Comment: it does not print anything on the shopping cart modal